# Play framework Java Drag and Drop table and save in models

Tags: playframework, drag-and-drop, tablerowsorter

I am new to `Play` framework (web development). I am struggling with drag and drop of table rows.Can anyone explain with a simple example for the case below:

I have a `View` that has a table with rows from `List` of Models. When the user drags and drops a row and click on a button to save the re-ordered table in the new order.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention , its Java in Play framework documentations are available for Scala only ..

Comment: Drag and drop is a client side feature, it has nothing to do with Play. So you have to look for something like http://interactjs.io.